# Make Columns Equal Height (both going up AND down)

Tags: jquery, css, height, multiple-columns

I use the following function to analyse two columns (content and a sidebar) and make sure the div's are equal height. This function only works when the columns need to increase in size. So when the content size decreases, it keeps the columns too big.

How can this code be changed to account for content decreasing in size (such as if the window size changes from a medium width to a large width, and where the tallest content height will decrease.)

```
var sidebarSameHeight = function() {
  //Sidebar Same Height - http://html-tuts.com/make-sidebar-same-height-as-content-div/
  // placing objects inside variables
  var content = $('.core_content_main');
  var sidebar = $('.core_content_sidebar');

  // get content and sidebar height in variables
  var getContentHeight = content.outerHeight();
  var getSidebarHeight = sidebar.outerHeight();

  // check if content height is bigger than sidebar
  if ( getContentHeight > getSidebarHeight ) {
    sidebar.css('min-height', getContentHeight);
  }

  // check if sidebar height is bigger than content
  if ( getSidebarHeight > getContentHeight ) {
    content.css('min-height', getSidebarHeight);
  }
};

sidebarSameHeight();
setInterval(sidebarSameHeight, 250);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code only checks if one columns is higher than the other. You need to repeat and inverse the logic to check if one is smaller than the other. We can't run both tests (bigger or smaller) each time so if we record the previous height we can then check that and decide which we need to do.

```
var sidebarSameHeight = function () {

// placing objects inside variables
var content = $('.core_content_main');
var sidebar = $('.core_content_sidebar');

// get content and sidebar height in variables
var getContentHeight = content.outerHeight();
var getSidebarHeight = sidebar.outerHeight();

//get the previous height
var contentOldHeight = content.data("oldHeight");
var sidebarOldHeight = sidebar.data("oldHeight");

//Check if either has reduced - if true use reduce logic for columns
if (contentOldHeight > getContentHeight || sidebarOldHeight > getSidebarHeight) {

   // check if content height is smaller than sidebar
    if (getContentHeight < getSidebarHeight) {
        sidebar.css('min-height', getContentHeight);
    }

   // check if sidebar height is smaller than content
    if (getSidebarHeight < getContentHeight) {
        content.css('min-height', getSidebarHeight);
    }

} else {

    // check if content height is bigger than sidebar
    if (getContentHeight > getSidebarHeight) {
        sidebar.css('min-height', getContentHeight);
    }
    // check if sidebar height is bigger than content
    if (getSidebarHeight > getContentHeight) {
        content.css('min-height', getSidebarHeight);
    }
}

//Set data values for next time
content.data("oldHeight", getContentHeight);
sidebar.data("oldHeight", getSidebarHeight);
};

sidebarSameHeight();
setInterval(sidebarSameHeight, 1000);
```

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyshd49u/) example allows you to type in the coloured boxes and see the boxes expanding and collapsing together. I upped the delay to one second to make it more obvious.

This may not be the complete solution for you but should get you on the way.